# Manually select option in Android AlerDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, multi-select

I have an AlertDialog with multi selection, which has a default "All" option, whereby if all other options are deselected this option will be selected while the dialog is still open.

However, I'm not sure how to manually select the default option. At the moment I have

```
List<T> selection = new ArrayList<>();
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(optionLabels, selectedArray, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            selection.add(options.get(which));
        } else {
            selection.remove(options.get(which));
        }

        if (selection.isEmpty()) {
            //manually select the default option here
        }
    }
})
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into that problem too, and found no way to accomplish this without using custom adapter. Below the code which works. Here i create the ListView manually, and set a custom adapter for it. And then on every item click check for selected items. If there's no item selected, i select a default item manually.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView modeList = new ListView(getActivity());
    MySimpleAdapter adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(getActivity());
    modeList.setAdapter(adapter);
    modeList.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    adapter.addAll(optionLabels);
    modeList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
            SparseBooleanArray selected = ((ListView) parent).getCheckedItemPositions();
            if (selected == null) {
                // That means our list is not able to handle selection
                // (choiceMode is CHOICE_MODE_NONE for example)
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < selected.size(); i++) {
                // This tells us the item position we are looking at
                int key = selected.keyAt(i);
                // And this tells us the item status at the above position
                boolean isChecked = selected.get(key);
                // And we can get our data from the adapter like that
                String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(key);
                if (isChecked) {
                    selection.add(item);
                } else {
                    selection.remove(item);
                }
            }

            // Nothing is selected
            if (selection.isEmpty()) {
                ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(positionOfDefaultItem,                true); // <-- Position of default option here
                String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(positionOfDefaultItem);
                selection.add(item);
            }
        }
    });

    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(modeList)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    _timePickerListener.onTimePeriodPicked(DialogSelectTime.this, _selectedPeriods);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Do nothing. Dialog is closed automatically
                }
            });

    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}

private class MySimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MySimpleAdapter(final Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this might be the only way. Thanks